# Using selenium WebDriver how can we make sure that extra elements are not displayed on page?

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver

My application is a permission based application. Page displays Check boxes and Radio buttons based on permissions to user. I have to verify that only those elements (Check boxes and Radio buttons) should be displayed on the page and not the once which are not permitted. To verify this in initial stage is easy but as and when application grows, number of elements will increase.

In that case, how can we make sure that elements whose permission are not given to user are not displayed on application user interface?

Comment: Use data driven testing techniques. Move the element details that are to be displayed in different test cases into an excel or database. Access it in your setup code and verfify. U can also have a look at bdd tools for this purpose

Comment: @Grasshopper :- Works for me. But if the application is small then i would prefer your option. Is it feasible to follow similar approach for application having more than 80 pages and which have more than 650 elements or more ?

Comment: I would do this kind of checking at the unit test level. Simpler to just use mocking for user rights and much much faster. Anyways if you want to check on the UI level, for smaller applications which have no chance of growing I would put it all in the test code. For anything else would move out this test data. In your case, would definitely use a database. Or else you can also have a look at applitools - https://applitools.com/ which is a visual testing tool. This works by comparing the current UI to a baseline UI.Integrates with selenium but it is not free.You can search for open source tool